# Partition Tables - Empty or Doesn't Exist

Tags: google-bigquery

Recently, I have been working on converting date suffixed tables into partitioned tables using ingestion time. However, in partition tables, how do we know whether certain date contains no data or the table was not created successfully?

Here is more details,

1. Previously, daily tables were created, but it is OK that some tables were empty because no result met the criteria. For example,

```
daily_table_20200601 (100 rows)
daily_table_20200602 (0 rows)
daily_table_20200603 (10 rows)
```

In this case, I can see table `daily_table_20200602` exists, so I know my scheduled job runs successfully.

2. When switching to partitioned tables using ingestion time, I am writing into the table `daily_table` every day, for example,

```
daily_table$20200601 (100 rows)
daily_table$20200602 (0 rows)
daily_table$20200603 (10 rows)
```

But how do we know the whether table `daily_table$20200602` was created successfully or it is just empty?

Also, there is something interesting. I am using API to check whether partition table exist, see the following code,

```
dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset_name')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table("daily_table$20210101")
client.get_table(table_ref)
```

The result shows the table exist. So are we able to check whether the certain date table exist or not?

Answer (score 1):

there's no separate (date table) for every partition, because the partitioning doesn't create a separate partition table, it's similar to relational database partitioning

ingestion time partitioning method adds a pseudo columns for day partitioning (_PARTITIONTIME,_PARTITIONDATE) and for hourly partitioning (_PARTITIONTIME) which will contains the timestamp of the beginning of the insertion data or hour and partition the table accordingly,

for this code:

```
dataset_ref = client.dataset('dataset_name')
table_ref = dataset_ref.table("daily_table$20210101")
client.get_table(table_ref)
```

This will success as long as the partitioned table exists

Comment: Thanks @Joe. Is that means we won't able to know whether certain date has no data or it wasn't being created at all?